# php zend gdata put a document/file into a category/folder Google Docs

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

How to attach a document/file to a category or folder using Zend gdata (oauth) in Google Docs ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Zend_Gdata_Docs::insertDocument()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/db_Gdata_Docs.html#%5CZend_Gdata_Docs%3a%3ainsertDocument%28%29) to add a resource to a collection/folder. See also the Google Documents List API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#adding_a_resource_to_a_collection

Comment: Thank you, yes i already spend too much time on this documentation but no example written in PHP that's a bit hard :/ I'm gonna try that ;)

Comment: Do you mind just editing you answer with an example because i got the header of the function:
$docs->insertDocument($data, $uri);
What do i use for $data and $uri, (i'm really sorry i'm completely lost)

Comment: I can show you how to use it. Please, just edit your question with the code where you determine your destination folder and where you have a reference to the resource/document/folder you want to add to this collection.

Comment: ok i think i've got it thanks for your answer, i don't know why i was thinking that learning the Google Docs API will be quick and easy and not so much in fact. Thank you ;)

Comment: Ok i'm still a bit stuck for the $uri, i did a new question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302008/zend-gdata-php-adding-an-entry-to-a-collection

Comment: Can you share with us how this was actually done? the answer really does not explain anything, not sure why it was made the accepted answer

Comment: Yeah can you please the solution? Thanks Jerome