# Zend GData upload file into a specific folder

Tags: php, google-docs-api, zend-gdata

I am trying to upload a file into a specific folder. I have the folder URI so I pass that as the URI in uploadFile function in Zend API.

However, I end up getting a 401 error.

This code works and uploads the file to the base of Google docs:

```
$newDocumentEntry = $docs->uploadFile($filePath, $documentTitle, null, Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI);
```

how do I create a URI that uploads it to a specific folder?

---

I am really strugling with this issue. I have tried everything I can think of to create a valid URI for specific folder but I always get the following error msg:

```
Expected response code 200, got 400
Invalid request URI
```

does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If someone can show me how to do this via Zend GData library, I would really appreciate it. I am trying to create a new folder (let's call it XYZ) and then upload a document to this folder (not the root folder)

Comment: Since no one has answered this, can I get my bounty back? :(

Answer (score 1):

[php zend gdata put a document/file into a category/folder Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299790/php-zend-gdata-put-a-document-file-into-a-category-folder-google-docs)

Is this what you are looking for?

If the error is 401, check if the authenticated google user really have permission to the folder for writing.

Comment: The user is authenticated, i just can't figure out a way to give it the write path to the specific folder. It does upload to the root google docs folder but I can't find a way to upload it to a specific folder..